# How can i convert a Seq in a Spark Rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, playframework

I'm using Spark Scala and Play Framework 
I have a seq like this

```
//a sequence of Book objects
val books:[Seq[Book]]
```

that i fill with the format method from a json file:

```
implicit val bookFormat: Format[Libri] = {
   ((JsPath \ "City").format[String] and
    (JsPath \ "GEN").format[Int] and
    (JsPath \ "SER").format[Int]    
    ) (Libri.apply , unlift(Libri.unapply)) }

val books = Json.parse(JsonString).as[Seq[Libri]]
```

How can i convert this seq in a Spark RDD. (I want to use this rdd for make some query...so i need the "registerTempTable" and "rdd.sqlContext.sql"

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sparkContext.parallelize(books)`. `parallelize` takes a collection and splits it into RDD. You can pass an additional parameter to define the number of partitions into which this seq will be split.

Comment: It doesn't work. When i make for example `val j = SparkCommons.sc.parallelize(books)`

Comment: Then j don't have methods like j.registerTempTable or j.sqlContext.sql etc.

Comment: Where is that `SparkCommons` variable coming from? How do you create the spark context?

Comment: `object SparkCommons {
  //build the SparkConf  object at once
  lazy val conf = {
    new SparkConf(false)
      .setMaster("local[*]")
      .setAppName("play demo")
      .set("spark.logConf", "true")
  }

  lazy val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
  lazy val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
}
`